# Database Link vs. JDBC Datasource

Tags: database-design, jdbc

Suppose a Java web application has a "main" database schema. However, there is another database schema that the web application needs to utalize.

Is it better to use 2 JDBC datasources or 1 JDBC datasource with a database link to the other schema?

Is the better architecture to minimize the number of datasources or the number of database links?

Answer (score 3):

> There is no "better" with the limited
>   information you've given. Period. How
>   will the data be consumed? What is the
>   nature of the data on the two servers?
>   Will it need to be joined to each
>   other? So many variables will
>   influence what is better.

Well that was going to be my comment but then I realized that you've setup a "False Alternative Problem" By suggesting that only A and B are answers when in fact C exists.

C is:

Have all three.

Is there some huge overhead to a database link? Not using it, just having it. Or having a datasource in your project? Would it crush a server if your project contained 3 datasources? or 7?

There are times when you you want data from one database...

Maybe there are times when you want data *only* from the other database...

Maybe there are times when you need to join data between the two...

All three 'connections' could be of use to you here.

But if those Maybe's turn into Never's, then you can remove one if you really want to.